# Angular 2 (global variables): How do I access a variable defined in index.html, in the Typescript code?

Tags: angular, global, nedb

I have this code:

```
 <script src="node_modules/nedb/browser-version/out/nedb.min.js"> </script>

 <script>
 var server = new Nedb({filename: 'someFile2', autoload: true});
 </script>
```

The Nedb persistent database is created.

I just want to access the server variable in the app code, like in MyCmp.ts. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare `Nedb` inside `Mycmp`, then you should call the initialization code.

```
declare var Nedb: any;

@Component(...)
export class MyCmp {

    server: any;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.server = new Nedb({filename: 'someFile2', autoload: true});
    }
}
```

Now you can access `this.server` inside other functions inside `Mycmp`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Where do I make this particular typings universal, so I don't need to keep declaring Nedb?

Comment: I guess my reputation is not enough.

Comment: Angular is great at dependency injection. You could initialize it in a service and then inject that into any other component that might need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access global variables by referencing window, like so

```
server = window["server"];
```

or

```
let server = window["server"];
```